# -Jquery- get values with one button which placed in same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to get element's values in div with button click and bring div's values into input box.

and I tried this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  $('.DA').on('click', '.submit_btn', function () {
      var getinfo = $(this).val();
      $('#val_input').val(getinfo); 
  });
};
```

this is my example.html

```
<input id="val_input">

<li class = 'CA'>
   <div class = 'DA'>
      <h1 id = 'HA'>name1</h1>
      <span class = 'SA'>info1-1</span>
      <span class = 'SB'>info1-2</span>
      <span class = 'SC'>info1-3</span>
      <button type = "submit" class = "submit_btn">submit</button>
   </div>
<li>
<li class = 'CA'>
   <div class = 'DA'>
      <h1 id = 'HA'>name2</h1>
      <span class = 'SA'>info2-1</span>
      <span class = 'SB'>info2-2</span>
      <span class = 'SC'>info2-3</span>
      <button type = "submit" class = "submit_btn">submit</button>
   </div>
<li>

...
```

I'm also tried to put one value in input box like this:

```
   window.onload = function () {
      $('.DA').on('click', '.submit_btn', function () {
          var getinfo = $(".SA").val();
          $('#val_input').val(getinfo); 
        });
      };
```

but it dosen't work.
I 'm very new to JS and Jquery so can't get a clue how to solve & where am I missing...

Comment: Fix typo `subimit_btn` != `submit_btn`

Comment: @u_mulder: Ok, I fixed my wrong typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.text()` instead of `.val()`. you will also need current clicked element context to target sibling span text:

```
    $('.DA').on('click', '.submit_btn', function () {
      var getinfo = $(this).prevAll(".SA").text();
      $('#val_input').val(getinfo); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

[check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/vsfv4Lf7/)

```
<input id="val_input">

<li class= 'CA'>
   <div class= 'DA'>
      <h1 id = 'HA'>name2</h1>
      <span class= 'SA'>info2-1</span>
      <span class= 'SB'>info2-2</span>
      <span class= 'SC'>info2-3</span>
      <button type= "button" class="subimit">submit</button>
   </div>
<li>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.subimit').click(function(){
      var getinfo = $(this).prevAll(".SA").text();
      $('#val_input').val(getinfo); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.subimit_btn', function() {
  var getinfo = $(this).text();
  $('#val_input').attr('value', getinfo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="val_input">

<li class = 'CA'>
   <div class = 'DA'>
      <h1 id = 'HA'>name1</h1>
      <span class = 'SA'>info1-1</span>
      <span class = 'SB'>info1-2</span>
      <span class = 'SC'>info1-3</span>
      <button type = "submit" class = "subimit_btn">submit</button>
   </div>
<li>
<li class = 'CA'>
   <div class = 'DA'>
      <h1 id = 'HA'>name2</h1>
      <span class = 'SA'>info2-1</span>
      <span class = 'SB'>info2-2</span>
      <span class = 'SC'>info2-3</span>
      <button type = "submit" class = "subimit">submit</button>
   </div>
<li>
```